# Последовательность целых и вещественных чисел через пробел

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Подскажите как составить регулярное выражение для последовательностей типа:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1.1 2.1 3.2 4.5
1 26.46 5 444.4 5.555
```

Должны допускаться целые и вещественные числа (разделенные точкой) через пробельный символ. Точка должна быть только одна. Остальные символы не допускаются.

Comment: вы бы уточнили в тексте вопроса, для чего именно вам нужны некие «регулярные выражения». а то ведь очевидный и абсолютно верный ответ `.*` вас наверняка не устроит.

Comment: Конечно, нет. Добавил описание.

Comment: Вам нужно что бы всю строчку проверял? Или что бы каждый токен строчки выводил?

Comment: Мне надо проверить так то строку на допустимые в ней символы (это цифры 0-9, пробел и точка). Например, как то так (^[0-9 .]+$). А потом из этой строки выбрать глобальным поиском шаблона в строке группы символов. То есть потом эти группы я запишу в обычный массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант сделать так:

```
([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]?)
```

Это не очень хорошо, потому что допускаются, например, это d1.1f 2.1 f3.2 4.5f 4f.5 4.f5. Небольшое в связи с этим дополнение:

Можно сначала проверить всю строку на допустимые символы вот так:

```
(^[0-9 .]+)$
```

Затем вытащить группы значений:

```
(([0-9])+([.][0-9]+)?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[\s$])+
```

[Протестировать](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99767)

А вот как в отфильтрованной строке найти группы:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы он не всю строку выделял целиком, а отдельные группы в строке? Например, 1.5 2.4 3.3 4.2 5.1. Выделятся 1.5, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.1.

Comment: @fedor-sg Вы сами написали в вопросе (ваш коментарий) выделять всю строку а потом в этой строке искать группы. Поиск группы по проверенной строке дописал в пример.

Comment: Тогда получается проверка по двум регуляркам :) А в одной это можно сделать?

Comment: @fedor-sg так у вас две операции 1 - проверка строки, 2 - выбор числа. Можно сразу число выбирать, но тогда проверку строки делать не будет.

Comment: То есть тут в любом случае две операции будет? Хитрых приемов нет, чтобы и проверили строку и выбрали элементы?

Comment: @fedor-sg Если для вас важно откидывать (определять) не валидные данные, то да. Если вас интересует только часть валидных данных, а не валидные вам достаточно просто пропускать, то можно сделать в один запрос.

Comment: @fedor-sg Вот пример `dfdf  11.11` если вы хотите как-то обработать что данные некоректные то вы делаете на это спец. запрос, а если просто получить 11.11 и все подобные, то можно одним запросом обойтись.

Comment: @fedor-sg но я бы, если честно, вообще бы по-другому сделал, я бы строчку разделил через split а потом каждое число по отдельности бы спарсил в число, и там уже либо возникнет ошибка либо нет, но решение зависит от задачи.

Comment: Согласен, решений много. Я решил через регулярку конвертировать в массив. Тогда в две регулярки оставлю. Если пользователь ввел косячные данные - его проблемы :).

Comment: @fedor-sg если вам моё решение помогло, вы можете отметить его как ответ.

Comment: Отметил что ответ был полезен. Пока не буду отмечать правильный ответ, может еще кто что скажет.